# Can't get color output in MacVim's command line

Tags: command-line, macvim

When I try and trigger PHPUnit tests within MacVim, I can't see coloured outputs in my command line:

[image]

Comment: Vim or GVim/MacVim?

Comment: @romainl I'm using MacVim

Comment: Then you can't get colored output. Try `:!phpunit --colors=auto` to disable color when the terminal doesn't support it. Not "pretty" but a lot *cleaner*.

Comment: @romainl I used `:!phpunit --colors=never`. Is this a MacVim thing?

Comment: Both MacVim and GVim come with a "dumb" terminal emulator that doesn't understand color. If you do `:!command` in Vim in a real terminal emulator, Vim is suspended and `command` is executed in the host shell which (hopefully) understands color escape sequences.

Comment: @romainl you should add that as an answer as that effectively explains my pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI version of Vim (MacVim on Mac OS X, GVim everywhere else) comes with a "dumb" terminal emulator that doesn't understand color at all.

If you want to run command-line programs without the ugly escape codes you'll need to either configure those programs to not use color when not possible or call them with dedicated options.

In your case:

```
:!vendor/bin/phpunit --colors=never ...
```

Since we are at it:

#### Git

The default value has been `auto` for a while but if you use an old release:

```
$ git config --global color.ui auto
```

#### Npm

This is a bit extreme but `npm` expects a boolean, here:

```
$ npm config set color=false
```

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same problem with `gvim` on Linux.

Put following in your `~/.gvimrc`

```
set guioptions+=!
```

Explanation from `:help guioptions`:

> '!'    External commands are executed in a terminal window.  Without
> this flag the MS-Windows GUI will open a console window to         execute
> the command.  The Unix GUI will simulate a dumb       terminal to list the
> command output.       The terminal window will be positioned at the
> bottom, and grow      upwards as needed.

Comment: This fixed MacVim for me, thanks!